# expected class-name before "{" token

Tags: c++

So far I've looked up most of the typical solutions for cases of this error and yet non of them seems to work with my code. I'm using dev-c++

The structure of problematic class is following.
m.hh

```
#ifndef M_H
#define M_H

#include "z.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class M: public Z
{                        /* this line is marked by the compiler as errorneous */
void m1();
void m2();
};

#endif
```

m.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "m.hh"

using namespace std;

void M::m1()                    {/*bla bla*/};
void M::m2()                        {/*bla bla*/};
}
```

EDIT:
z.hh

```
#ifndef Z_H
#define Z_H

#include "m.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

class Z;

static Z* s(string g, string i);

#endif
```

z.cpp

```
#include "z.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Z
{


public:
    string i;
    string g;

    void set_i(string im)                       {i = im;}
    string get_i()                              {return i;}
    string get_g()                          {return g;}
    virtual void m1()=0;
    virtual void m2()=0;
    Z* s(string g, string i)    {
        Z * z;
        if(g=="m"){
            M * z = new M;

        }
    }

};
```

Thanks!

Comment: in `m.cpp` you don't need the `;` at the end of methods definition. Also you have an extra `}` at the last line. And please post what `z.hh` contain

Comment: Can you show header file containing the z class as well?

Comment: The error means that the compiler does not know that `Z` is a name of a class. Since you are including `z.hh`, I am assuming that the most common problem (i.e. failure to include the header) is out of the question. Show your z.hh, the problem is probably there.

Comment: I concur with blinken. Additionally it's common to include user headers after the system headers. I think the main reason is that the system headers may define things the user needs, and they should not accidentally be altered by defines and declarations in the user headers.

Comment: @WileTheCoyot yep, just sec

Comment: Well, the cpp file is actually a class declaration and should be a header file.

Comment: Also be aware that the decalaration `static Z* s(string g, string i);` is a different function from the member function with the same name and parameters in Z! Probably not intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

You cannot derive from an incomplete type, which is what `Z` is in `m.hh`.

Upon deriving from a type the compiler must know the definition of said type. Just imagine you are trying to call a derived member function from `Z` on an object of type `M`, how would the compiler know if such call is a valid construct without knowing if `Z` actually declares such member?

And, a more relevant point, how would `M` be able to initialize `Z` without knowing what `Z` is?

---

**THE SOLUTION**

Move the definition of `class Z` to `z.hh`, and leave the definitions of its member functions in `z.cpp` (the same way you have split up `M` across `m.hh`, and `m.cpp`).

Answer (score 3):

Remove `#include "m.hh"` from `z.hh` to fix the circular include.

Comment: Not nice but not the prob since caught by include guards.

Comment: when I remove the said statement I get "'m' was not declared in this scope" error

Comment: @m.woj you need to include m.hh in z.cpp for that.

Comment: @PeterSchneider include guards don't help against circular includes. They're there to prevent multiple includes of the same header in the same translation unit.

Comment: Well, they do, and then they don't. They do prevent infinite recursive inclusion, but they don't solve the OP's logical problem (that both classes need to know each other because he wants to implement a static factory function but made it a member function).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the z.cpp file is actually a class declaration and should be a header file. A forward decalaration is only sufficient when you deal with pointers to that class, but not for inheriting from one (the compiler does need to know z's class layout for that).

The z.hh is not really needed, and the function declaration in it is not what you think (it's not a member function declaration). You can delete it and rename z.cpp to z.hh.

Ok, the exchange with @Luchian Grigore made me realize what you probably wanted and why you had "two z.hh". Z is to produce an M, but M inherits from Z, so there is a circular dependency. In C/C++ the way to break such a circle is to limit what one of the classes needs to know from the other: In order to declare a member function s that produces a pointer to a new M Z's class *declaration* only needs a typename M, not a the whole class declaration. So just a forward declaration (`class M;`) that introduces the type name M into the declaration of Z is enough; if the pointer to the M object is returned as a pointer to the base, Z, M's name is not even needed at all when Z is *declared*.

The *definition* of the factory function (be it file static or a member function) needs, if it is to produce an M, M's complete declaration though. That would be in a seaparate cpp file, which would include a complete header with M's full declaration.